# How can I revert to original color if I use Replace and RegExp?

Tags: jquery, colors, textarea

I'm working on a builder. The user is supposed to click on images that represents html components, and this inject the html in a textarea. The template comes with a main color (background, highlighted text, links etc)

I created a row of buttons, to let the user change the main color (for example #000000).

```
<button class="change black-color" id="black-color">Black</button>    
<button class="change blue-color" id="blue-color">Blue</button>
<button class="change green-color" id="green-color">Green</button> etc....
```

Then with jquery the clik on button changes all occurences of black to the new color:

```
    $("#myDiv button").click(function(){
      var textarea=$('#myTextarea'); 
      if($(this).attr('id') === 'blue-color'){
        textarea.html(textarea.html().replace(new RegExp("#000000","g"),"#d20606")); 
      }else if($(this).attr('id') === 'green-color'){
        textarea.html(textarea.html().replace(new RegExp("#000000","g"),'#ff4c00'));
      }else if($(this).attr('id') === 'light-color'){
        textarea.html(textarea.html().replace(new RegExp("#000000","g"),'#31B7BC'));
      }
```

etc...for all next colors....

**My question is** : is there a way to shorten the function to make it more dynamic and how can I revert back to black color (the first main color) with RegExp ??

**EDIT:**
thanks to freedomn-m all this code can be shorten using data-attribute through html..but I still have a question

If I have an array of hexa code, how can I make the following :
I you find a color in the textarea that correspond to one of the color of the array, change all occurences of that color to the button( data-color) clicked by user.

For example :

```
var color =["#64A70B","#525ca3","#d20606","#ff4c00","#61b09d","#00cbf9","#31B7BC","#4EAB8E"];
$(".change").click(function() {
  var colour = $(this).data("color");

  var textarea = $('#myTextarea'); 
   textarea.html(textarea.html().replace(color, colour)); 
  
});
```

Comment: Toggle a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I manage to make something more dynamic. I'm not using Regex.I create a array of hexa code. I browse it, and for each corresponding color found in the textarea, I replace it with the one injected by the clicked button. So if there are some #64A70B color, and if I click on data-color="#525ca3" button, all instances of #64A70B are replace by #525ca3 and so on.

```
 var color["#64A70B","#525ca3","#d20606","#ff4c00","#61b09d","#00cbf9","#31B7BC","#4EAB8E"];

 $(".change").click(function() { 
  var colour = $(this).data("color");
  var textarea = $('#myTextarea');
  var len = color.length;
  for (i=0; i < len; i++) {
    textarea.html(textarea.html().replaceAll(color[i], colour)); 
  }  
});
```

Maybe this code could be improved, but it seems to work well..Thank you freedomn-m, you put me on the right direction, but it didn't totaly solve my issue..

Answer (score 0):

Put the colour inside the button, not the code.  Then you can add new buttons without changing your code

```
<button class="change" data-color='#000000'>Black</button>    
<button class="change" data-color='#d20606'>Blue</button>
<button class="change" data-color='#ff4c00'>Green</button>
```

then

```
$(".change").click(function() {
  var colour = $(this).data("color");

  var textarea = $('#myTextarea'); 
  textarea.html(textarea.html().replace(/#000000/g, colour)); 
});
```

---

to change the colour more than once, you could use a regex, but it might be hit and miss depending on what else they put in the text area, eg

```
.replace(/\=\"\#\d{6}\"/g, '="' + colour + '"')
```

(probably don't need all the \escape, but doesn't do harm)

giving

```
$(".change").click(function() {
  var colour = $(this).data("color");

  var textarea = $('#myTextarea'); 
  textarea.html(textarea.html().replace(/\=\"\#\d{6}\"/g, '="' + colour + '"')); 
});
```

Comment: wonderful, thank you very much freedomn-m !! I edited my question, Thanks to your answer I think Itmight be possible to improve the user exeprience here, but don't know how to do with the right syntax..

Comment: If my answer helped your original problem, please accept it (and upvote if you like).  Then I suggest you ask a new, follow-on question as you'll more likely to get an expediented answer